# Join Tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql query like this

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `IPK` AS select 
`ipbmst_fakultas`.`Kode` AS `Fakultas`,
`ipbmst_departemen`.`Kode` AS `Departemen`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` AS `NIM`,
`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`TahunMasuk` AS `TahunMasuk`,
 `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`IPK` AS `IPK`
from (((((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister` join `akdmst_mayor` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`MayorID` = `akdmst_mayor`.`ID`))) 
join `ipbmst_departemen` on((`akdmst_mayor`.`DepartemenID` = `ipbmst_departemen`.`ID`))) 
join `ipbmst_fakultas` on((`ipbmst_departemen`.`FakultasID` = `ipbmst_fakultas`.`ID`))) 
join `ipbmst_orang` on((`akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`))) 
left join `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi` on((`akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`NIM` = `ipbmst_orang`.`NIMS2Key`)));
```

but, when I tried to open the view, the data couldn't be opened. Maybe it is because of "akdhis_kelanjutanstudi" table that consists of more than 300K data. What should I do to solve this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Create a temporary table from this huge data. Then select limited number of rows from the temporary table using `limit`. Paginate the result set to the end.

Comment: I have used "limit" though. But, the data still couldn't be opened :( @arsho

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM yourTable
);
SELECT * FROM tempTable  ORDER BY anyColumn LIMIT 50,500;`  This will show rows 51 - 550

Answer (score 0):

Create InDex On Table "akdhis_kelanjutanstudi" Column "NIM"
Or

Try To INSERT In Dynamic table   FROM  table "akdhis_kelanjutanstudi"
Then Left Join On "Dynamic table"
and use some filter in query..

Comment: I still dont understand how to use those codes. could you please give me an example?

Comment: step1:   akdhis_kelanjutanstudi Insert Into Dynamic table 2. Then Join Dynamic table instense of Orginal table

Comment: could you please give me the sql code? because I still don't get how to write the codes